# How to Enable-Migrations In Code Camper Project

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, entity-framework

I have been working my way through the Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1 on Pluralsight by John Papa.  Shortly after getting the basic pieces of the application together I wanted to make sure I could get EF Migrations to work, but I cannot figure out the best way to start.

The Solution has 3 separate projects:

1. CC.DataAccess --  DBContext is in here.
2. CC.Model - POCO classes
3. CC.Web  - Where the actual database is

What is the best way to Enable-Migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following steps:

Run the Enable-Migrations command on DataAccess project
Run the Add-Migration command with the ConnectionStringName parameter specified
Run the Update-Database command

The following is a good EF Migrations Command Reference: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Enable-Migrations